# Why does my import time give error module object is not callable

Tags: python, time

I just want to use the import time function to get a timestamp from python.

```
import time
```

I have this sample test code which works just fine on cloud 9.

```
import time
now = int(time.time() * 1000)
print now
```

But it doesn't work on my mac. I get an error right on line 1.

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar 21 2016, 23:21:56) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "time.py", line 2, in <module>
    now = int(time.time() * 1000)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>>
```

Not sure what is going on here it is frustrating.

Comment: You may have a file named time.py in the current directory. Don't do that - you're *shadowing* the real time module.

Answer (score 6):

You have a file in your local directory called "time.py". Rename it.

Comment: This worked. I had named my test file time.py.  When I removed it the code worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error and found I'd put

```
time.sleep=2
```

in a different class.

Corrected to

```
time.sleep(2)
```

and the error went away.